# Checking for rectangle overlap in multi-dimensional array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, procedural

So I'm making a procedural dungeon maker, right now I store the map in a multi-dimensional array. I plot n number of rooms of random positions and random sizes all of which are rectangles. As seen below:

[image]

'X' represents part of a room and '.' represent empty space. As you can see since I am randomly generating the size and position of these rooms some of these rooms overlap, this can be seen in the image.

My question is how would I go about checking if there are overlapping rectangles and therefore remove the overlapping rectangles? Not asking anyone to code this, I'm just struggling with understanding the logic.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea not to store data as an array. You can have array of rooms. Every time you add new room you can easily check that this room does not overlap any of existing rooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) make a 2D array like that and check for X's BEFORE you put a room there ;-) If there are X's, don't put the new room there to begin with. Doesn't have to be rocket science. Remember you have control over this. Put the room-making logic in a method that can see your grid and room dimensions, have it operate in 2 modes: mode1=return TRUE if overlapping, mode 2, update the grid. call it once to see if you have a good good spot for a new room, if not, make another room!

2) brute force compares: (pseudocode) this is if you have an array of individual drawing.2d.rectangles.

```
bool collides(rect newrect, rect[] allrects) 
    for each item in allrects
        if item.intersects(newrect)
            return true
```

There, I didn't 'code' it ;-)

Before adding a new rectangle, call this routine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, checking if there are X's before I add the room did the job for me. Cheers!